# DataReader is displaying Yahoo Finance dates incorrectly

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I am running this code to get timeseries data for USDJPY:

```
from pandas_datareader import data
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

data.DataReader('JPY=X', 'yahoo', date(2020,6,15), date(2020,6,28))['Close']
```

This is producing the following:

```
Date
2020-06-14    107.310997
2020-06-15    107.463997
2020-06-16    107.410004
2020-06-17    106.893997
2020-06-18    107.005997
2020-06-21    106.831001
2020-06-22    106.903000
2020-06-23    106.431999
2020-06-24    107.043999
2020-06-25    107.154999
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

These dates are wrong. 14 and 21 June 2020 were Sundays. The currency data is correct but the dates are all being shifted backwards by 1 day (i.e. 14 June 2020 should be 15 June 2020

Comment: Where do you load the data from? What does it look like, especially the dates? This could be due to a timezone difference between Japan and your local timezone

Comment: I am in Singapore, which is 1 hours behind Japan.

Comment: Yahoo Finance doesn't have an API - it was discontinued in 2017. How do you get that data? How? Using screen scraping? I don't see the values you posted [in the relevant Yahoo Finance page](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/USDJPY%3DX/history?period1=1591747200&period2=1593043200&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d). The problem is in the screen scraping code, not DataReader

Comment: I use the code data.DataReader('JPY=X', 'yahoo', date(2020,6,15), date(2020,6,28))['Close'] which seems to be pulling it from Yahoo Finance via API, or so I thought...

Comment: Yahoo is [not in the list of built-in data sources](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which means you had to add another one. How did you do that? Which source did you add? Please add enough code to reproduce your issue

Comment: from pandas_datareader import data
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

This is what I ran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer. Don't use DataReader for FX data. Use Alpha Vantage as follows:

```
import requests

Get = requests.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=FX_DAILY&from_symbol=usd&to_symbol=jpy&outputsize=full&apikey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
```

You will need to request an API key [here](https://www.alphavantage.co/support/#api-key).